# Stationary distribution of (Xn+1, Xn)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> If ${X_n}$ is a Markov chain with stationary distribution (3/7, 4/7) , with state space {(0,1)}
> Show that ${(X_n, X_{n+1})}$ is also a markov chain and compute the stationary distribution.

It is obvious that  ${(X_n, X_{n+1})}$ depends on ${(X_{n-1}, X_{n})}$ only.
But is the stationary distribution =
$(\begin{array}{cc} 
3/7*3/7 &3/7*4/7 &4/7*3/7& 4/7*4/7\\ 
\end{array})$
=$(\begin{array}{cc} 
9/49 &12/49 &12/49& 16/7\\ 
\end{array})$